# Having German Blue card, working in Luxemburg, getting Germany permanent residence permit

Tags: germany, blue-card, luxembourg

I hold a German Blue Card and got a job offer from a company in Luxemburg. My question is that if I stay in Germany (Trier) and work in Luxemburg, can I finally get Germany permanent residence after 3 years?

Comment: Can you even stay in Germany with a job in Luxembourg? How long have you held your German Blue Card? Worked in Germany? And which kind of permanent residence are you interested in? *Niederlassungserlaubnis* or *Daueraufenthalt-EU*?

Answer (score 1):

With a job in Luxembourg, you won't be paying into the German mandatory retirement system and therefore won't be eligible for permanent residency after 33/48 months (or ever, actually) unless you are already eligible (directly or through a spouse). That's true even if you are able to hold onto your EU Blue Card and keep residing in Trier, which is not obvious to me (but that's another question).